# Flutter how to add padding in TextFormField?

Tags: flutter, dart

I hope the title is enough to understand what i want, How to add padding and margin in TextFormField? please see picture below for more information. thanks

```
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png'),
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                filled: true,
                border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                    const Radius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                ),
                labelText: 'Enter your username'),
          ),
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                filled: true,
                border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                    const Radius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                ),
                labelText: 'Enter your password'),
          ),
        ],
      )
```

[image]

Comment: if you want padding and margin you can wrap it with container and add margin there

Comment: Why not use directly Padding widget?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use several methods to increase the distance from them:

1. `SizedBox()`
2. `Padding()`
3. `Container(margin , child: ...)`

> **1-** **`SizedBox()`**:

```
child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png'),
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                filled: true,
                border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                    const Radius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                ),
                labelText: 'Enter your username'),
          ),
          SizedBox(height:10), // will add 10 pixels 
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                filled: true,
                border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                    const Radius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                ),
                labelText: 'Enter your password'),
          ),
        ],
      )
```

> **2- `Padding()`**

```
 Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  filled: true,
                  border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                      const Radius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  labelText: 'Enter your username'),
            ),
          ),
```

> **3-** **`Container()`**

```
     Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
        child: TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          fillColor: Colors.white,
          filled: true,
          border: new OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
              const Radius.circular(10.0),
            ),
          ),
          labelText: 'Enter your password'),
  ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 3):

Please wrap TextFormField in the Container and set margin like as top, left, right, bottom according your ui. Please check this and If this it's correct so please tell me.

```
Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10,left: 0,right: 0,bottom: 0),
                child: TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  filled: true,
                  border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                      const Radius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  labelText: 'Enter your password'),
          ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 1):

To apply horizontal padding just add `Padding` widget above your `Column`:

```
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png'),
      // your text fields
    ],
...
```

To add vertical padding use `SizedBox` inside `Column`:

```
child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png'),
          TextFormField1(...),
          SizedBox(height: 24.0),
          TextFormField2(...),
          SizedBox(height: 24.0),
        ],
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

InputDecoration takes a contentPadding value.  Just use that directly.

Answer (score 0):

you can add SizedBox.

```
 TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                filled: true,
                border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                    const Radius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                ),
                labelText: 'Enter your username'),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                filled: true,
                border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                    const Radius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                ),
                labelText: 'Enter your password'),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert sizedbox in between the textformfield like:-

```
child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png'),
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                filled: true,
                border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                    const Radius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                ),
                labelText: 'Enter your username'),
          ),
          SizedBox(height:30), // will add 30 pixels gap in between the fields
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                filled: true,
                border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                    const Radius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                ),
                labelText: 'Enter your password'),
          ),
        ],
      )
```